# copy a folder inside a php-generated one

Tags: php, html, function, shell

I'm having big trouble trying to do a simple thing and after 2 days I've decided to ask some one wiser (you).

I am doing the following:

```
$paquete = uniqid();
    $path = '../resources/TEMP/'.$paquete;
    $player = '../resources/portable';
    $books = '../resource/books';
    $products = '/opt/lampp/htdoc/portablecreator/resources/TEMP/'.$paquete.'/desktop_macmillan_v1_7_linux/site/www/root/products/';
    putenv('TMPKG='. $products);    
    temppkg($paquete);
    recurse_copy($player, $path);
```

I create one folder using a php-function:

```
function temppkg($cadena) {
  $dir = '../resources/TEMP/'.$cadena;
  if(!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    chmod($dir, 0777);
    return $dir;}
```

Then inside this one I copy the content of other one using another function:

```
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $fld = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst, 0777, true);
    chmod($dst, 0777);
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($fld)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($fld); 
}
```

All of this goes fine and the structure is created. The problem comes when I try to copy inside this folder structure the content of another folder. I'm using a shell script that uses the environment varible declared at the beggining:

```
putenv('TMPKG='. $products);
```

The shell code is:

```
cp -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/portablecreator/resources/books/pulse1 $TMPKG/;
```

And I call it (if a checkbox is marked) doing this:

```
if(isset($_POST['book']) && $_POST['book'] = 6 ){
    shell_exec ('sh /script/6.sh'); }
```

The problem is that the task that the sh has to do is not done and no fail is displayed.

Any idea?

Thank you very much in advance